# newbie tries to split Javascript list of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, parsing

I have this list in Javascript:

```js
[
    'name: John',
    'age: 30',
    'title: engineer',
    '',
    'name: Steve',
    'age: 40',
    'title: CEO',
    '',
    'name: Richard',
    'age: 36',
    'title: n/a'
]
```

I want to split it into 3 new lists:

```js
[
    'name: John',
    'age: 30',
    'title: engineer',
]
[
    'name: Steve',
    'age: 40',
    'title: CEO',
]
[
    'name: Richard',
    'age: 36',
    'title: n/a'
]
```

Even better, if it's possible to create a dictionary like this:

```js
{
    John: {
        'name: John',
        'age: 30',
        'title: engineer'
    },
    Steve: {
        'name: Steve',
        'age: 40',
        'title: CEO'
    },
    Richard: {
        'name: Richard',
        'age: 36',
        'title: n/a'
    }
}
```

Could you help me with the solution, I just started to work with JS and know nothing about it.
Thanks!

Comment: Your output is not valid

Comment: How do you retrieve the input array? I think the problem is with this array in the first place. It's very weird structure I think

Comment: what kind of JSON in that, and where you are getting this from

Comment: There is a huge difference between `{
        'name: John',
        'age: 30',
        'title: engineer'
    }` and `{
        name: 'John',
        age: '30',
        title: 'engineer'
    }`, if only because the first variant (an object containing unnamed properties) is impossible in Javascript. Please **[edit]** the question to reflect the output that you really need, and also make it *actually achievable* output.

Comment: I have a service from where I got this response. It's plain text. I created a list
```
serviceResponse.split('\n');
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with valid input and output objects

Comment: Your `even better` example, what would happen if you had 2 John's or Steve's etc.

Comment: The problem is that it is not a JSON, it's just a plain text, and I need to parse it somehow. It doesn't matter how..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to split it into 3 lists:

```js
const arr = ['name: John', 'age: 30', 'title: engineer', '', 'name: Steve', 'age: 40', 'title: CEO', '', 'name: Richard', 'age: 36', 'title: n/a']

const lists = arr.reduce((a, e) => (e !== '' ? a[a.length - 1].push(e) : a.push([]), a), [[]])

console.log(lists)
```

then you can put the lists into an object, using `Object.fromEntries` alongside `reduce` again:

```js
const lists = [
  ["name: John", "age: 30", "title: engineer"],
  ["name: Steve", "age: 40", "title: CEO"],
  ["name: Richard", "age: 36", "title: n/a"]
]

const objects = lists.map(l => Object.fromEntries(l.map(e => e.split(': '))))
const output = objects.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.name] = o, a), {})

console.log(output)
```